# Django: Celery only works on local but not production using the cookiecutter project

Tags: django, docker, celery, django-celery

I set up a project using the django cookie cutter and deployed it with the docker option https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-with-docker.html

Celery perfectly works on my local machine and gives me a lot of logging information but on production i get nothing about Celery or redis at all. (I'm using Redis as the worker).
Since i'm new to celery and couldn't find anything inside the cookiecutter or the celery doc i thought one of you might know more.

Is there anything i have to do differently when using Celery with the django cookiecutter?
Or is there a way to debug this? So far i tried the internal caprover logs and the docker logs.

This is my dockerfile for production:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9-slim-bullseye



# define an alias for the specfic python version used in this file.
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION} as python

# Python build stage
FROM python as python-build-stage

ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=production

# Install apt packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # dependencies for building Python packages
  build-essential \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  libpq-dev

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements .

# Create Python Dependency and Sub-Dependency Wheels.
RUN pip wheel --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels  \
  -r ${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}.txt


# Python 'run' stage
FROM python as python-run-stage

ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=production
ARG APP_HOME=/app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV BUILD_ENV ${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}

WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

RUN addgroup --system django \
    && adduser --system --ingroup django django


# Install required system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  libpq-dev \
  # Translations dependencies
  gettext \
  # cleaning up unused files
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# All absolute dir copies ignore workdir instruction. All relative dir copies are wrt to the workdir instruction
# copy python dependency wheels from python-build-stage
COPY --from=python-build-stage /usr/src/app/wheels  /wheels/

# use wheels to install python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links=/wheels/ /wheels/* \
  && rm -rf /wheels/


COPY --chown=django:django ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint


COPY --chown=django:django ./compose/production/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start
RUN chmod +x /start
COPY --chown=django:django ./compose/production/django/celery/worker/start /start-celeryworker
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celeryworker
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker


COPY --chown=django:django ./compose/production/django/celery/beat/start /start-celerybeat
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celerybeat
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat


COPY ./compose/production/django/celery/flower/start /start-flower
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-flower
RUN chmod +x /start-flower
VOLUME captain---voldata:/app

# copy application code to WORKDIR
COPY --chown=django:django . ${APP_HOME}

# make django owner of the WORKDIR directory as well.
RUN chown django:django ${APP_HOME}

USER django

CMD ["/start"]
```

CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER is set to False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't aware that you apparently have to set up two almost identical Django installs because gunicorn is already occupying the shell on production. On the other Django instance you just run celery instead.